# Undefined variable and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i'm trying to learn `codeigniter` and i have problem here. There was an error Undefined variable and Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on view. here is the code :

Model (Model_Users.php) :

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getFirstNames(){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT firstname FROM users');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    function getUsers(){

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller (welcome.php) :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_users');

        $data['title'] = 'MVC Cool Title';
        $data['page_header']='Intro to MVC Design';
        $data['firstnames'] = $this->model_users->getFirstNames();

        $data['users'] = $this->model_users->getUsers();

        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

View (Welcome_message.php) :

```
<div id="container">
    <h1><?php echo $page_header ?></h1>

    <div id="body">
        <?php
            foreach ($firstnames as $object) {
                echo $object->firstname .'<br/>';
            }
            echo '<br/><hr/><br/>';

            foreach ($users as $object){
                echo $object->firstname . '\'s email address is'. $object->email . '<br/>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>
```

Please help me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: what is this value `$firstnames` or `$users` are both set?  I think at lest one is missing.  put `var_dump($firstnames);` and `var_dump($users);` before the foreach.

Comment: are you sure that you have data in the table ? because if u dont, it is returning a NULL. and NULL is an invalid arguement for foreach.

Comment: Yep as others have noted... your are either returning an array or a NULL but you are not testing for the NULL. So that might be a good idea to test for before performing your foreach loops?

Comment: Just an aside. I realise you are just starting out and having a play which is grand... But consider the case where you are performing a query on the users table, one for firstname and then one for everything. Could you achieve this with a single call to the users table?

Answer (score 0):

First check value return any value or not write this code in controller 
use

`var_dump($firstnames)`;
and 
`var_dump($users)`;

I think no data return from model
check any data in table
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the error by using `return [];` instead of `return null;` instead of checking for that case in every foreach call, because it appears that your user table might be empty based on the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model functions like below

```
function getFirstNames(){
    $query = $this->db->get('users')->row()->firstname;

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

function getUsers(){


    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

hope this will help